# How do I determine if a Component is Published based on the current TargetType

Tags: 2011, publishing, templating, tom.net

I'm using `Component.IsPublishedInContext` to determine if the Component is published but the value returns true irrespective of the current `TargetType` where the Component is being published to.

Example:

1. Component is Published as a DCP to "Staging"
2. Component is NOT Published to "Live"
3. `Component.IsPublishedInContext` returns `true` when being executed on "Live"

How do I figure out if the Component is published to "Live"?

Comment: Welcome to Tridion stack exchange.. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange.

Can you let us know which version of Tridion you are using please?

**If you are using Tridion 2011**, then I think that this has already been answered (by Bart) in Rob's "*Tridion 2009 TBB: How do I determine if a Page is published to particular publication target?*" question over on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772321/tridion-2009-tbb-how-do-i-determine-if-a-page-is-published-to-particular-public/9786517#9786517).

The `PublishEngine.IsPublished(IdentifiableObject item, PublicationTarget publicationTarget, bool isPublishedInContext)` method should give you this.

**If you are using Tridion 2009**, then [Ryan's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9802682/197993) on [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772321/tridion-2009-tbb-how-do-i-determine-if-a-page-is-published-to-particular-public) should work.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I am using Tridion 2011 SP1 and yes using PublishEngine.IsPublished solved my problem! Thank you!